# Checking battery voltage with ADC and interrupts - which way is best?

Tags: c, embedded

Here are some stripped down versions of the two different programs I am deciding between.

In version one, my state machine is called within the interrupt:

```
void TimerInterrupt(void)
{
    int battery_voltage;

    StartADC();

    while(ADCrunning){}

    battery_voltage = ADC_value * scale_factor;

    BatteryStateMachine(battery_voltage);
}

void main (void)
{
    StartTimer();

    while(1){}
}
```

In version two, the interrupt populates a global variable, and my main program has a while loop wherein a function is called whenever that global variable changes:

```
int battery_voltage;

void TimerInterrupt(void)
{
    StartADC();

    while(ADCrunning){}

    battery_voltage = ADC_value * scale_factor;
}

void main (void)
{
    int old_battery_voltage;

    StartADC();

    while(ADCrunning){}

    old_battery_voltage = ADC_value * scale_factor;

    StartTimer();

    while(1){
        if (battery_voltage == old_battery_voltage){}
        else {
            BatteryStateMachine(battery_voltage);
        }
    }
}
```

What are the questions I need to ask in order to determine which of these is better for my requirements? Or is one of these methods already clearly superior to the other, and I just don't know it?

Comment: You should know what do you want to ask before typing a question and develop said question according to your doubts, in my opinion, here you are asking which of the two methods is better and why one is superior to the other. In my opinion you should post an explanation of the problem you are facing (an event which needs to be timed), the solution/s you came up with and how you feel about it.

Comment: Also how much time you've been developing? I see some flaws in this code that frequently happen to beginners in programming

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: An interrupt function is special. It does not behave in the same way as a normal function you should not be doing any serious work in the interrupt callback function (there are a lot of caveats about what is actually allowed). As such your best bet is to set a global flag that is handled by your main code in normal user space.

Comment: This is hypothetical or incomplete code. Here at Code Review we review working, non-hypothetical code.

Comment: This is not hypothetical code, but it is incomplete -  I have taken two versions of working code and stripped them down to ask my question. As this is an embedded application the complete working code would be massive and highly specific. Is there a better way or place to ask my question?

Answer (score 4):

First rule when using microcontrollers is:

**Do as little as you can in the interrupt function!**

Explanation:
Consider having 10 or 100 interrupts configured. Each interrupt function will take 100 or 200 ms to deal with. (Sounds quite low, but when you have a bigger project with a big controller this might be possible)

Then 4 or 5 interrupts will arise and you have to configure the priorities all with priorities that are (maybe) included in microcontroller hardware.

If you don't have this hardware priorities (I this the small Microchip's don't have these?) you can't handle priorities.

Second thing: I don't know which microcontroller you use, but I think it has a flag that shows if the ADC is finished. Use this for `ADCrunning` (you don't show where you define it).

So my approach would be:

```
 volatile bool startADC;   // edit: you can use a struct, if there will be too many flags

void TimerInterrupt(void)
{
    startADC = true;
}

void main (void)
{

    int battery_voltage;
    int old_battery_voltage;

    battery_voltage = 0;
    old_battery_voltage = -1;

    StartTimer();

    while(1){
        if (startADC = true) {
            StartADC();
            startADC = false;
        }

        // use the flag as mentioned above 
        if (ADCFinished = true) {
            // you might think of using the scale factor 
            battery_voltage = ADC_value * scale_factor;
            ADCFinished = false;
        }

        // use unequal instead of the "== else"-construct
        if (battery_voltage != old_battery_voltage) {
            BatteryStateMachine(battery_voltage);
            old_battery_voltage = battery_voltage; // you need this here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `if (battery_voltage <> old_battery_voltage)` won't compile.  The operator in C is `!=`.

Comment: The `startADC` variable should be `volatile` and probably also `static`.

Comment: Yes, it should. But the code is just to show a good way to use the interrupt system at all

Answer (score 3):

I see a **major flaw** in this code right off the bat and that is your *interruption management*.

In my opinion, you are **not treating an interruption as such**, you are treating the timer as a function instead of a **source of interruption** in the behaviour of your normal code so a question arises.

- Have you **checked if the execution time of the interruption code takes longer than the timer's cycle** you've set? In that case you have a very serious problem which will make your program not behave like you want

Again, as I see it, this program does not treat an interruption as such, so I'll give you an explanation of how I've been learned to treat them and how it can improve your code.

First of all, an interruption is a **source which interrupts the currently executing code to execute another that expects an event**. Due to this behavioral, an interruption should be always as short as possible.

An interruption needs to be as short as possible because if **you can call an interruption before it has ended** (like in the case you are experiencing) it will overflow the stack pointer at some point in your execution and cause your device to not perform correctly. This happens because when calling an interruption the embedded saves where it is, performs the interruption/s (if more than one has triggered) and then comes back to where it was and resumes normal program execution.

Do you see the main problem in your code with what I've explained here? If *your interruption takes longer than the time you call it periodically*, you will never exit the interruption, thus regarding your code unusable while also making *your embedded to perform badly or not as expected* at some point because of an overflow in the stack pointer.

Because of this, an **interruption should only consist of flag management** which will be used in turn to **allow the code intended to be executed** in said interruption in the **main body** in your code. You might ask yourself how you can do this, so I'll give an example of how to implement this on your own code.

```
bool flagADCConversion = false;
bool flagADCReady = false;

void TimerInterrupt(void)
{
  flagADCConversion  = true;
}

void main (void)
{
    StartTimer();

    while(1)
    {
        if (flagADCConversion)
        {
            // Start the ADC here, but don't wait for its reading, just set a flag to prevent the next iteration of your code from restarting the ADC
            StartADC();
            flagADCConversion = false;
        }

        if (flagADCReady)
        {
            // When the ADC notifies it has a valid reading, you can proceed to read from it, and then as the task is completed, you can lower any flag/s involved
            battery_voltage = ADC_value * scale_factor;

            BatteryStateMachine(battery_voltage);

            flagADCReady = false;
        }  
    }
}
```

The code here has improved in many ways to your iteration, I'll list them in the following:

1. First and foremost, You now don't have to worry if it takes longer for the code to execute than the timer to fire, since you have control over whether or not the program has to read from the ADC.
2. Secondly, your program can execute many things while the ADC performs a conversion (essentially we've made the ADC conversion a task which we launch and later ask for its result), this might remind you of asynchronous code.

So to conclude, an *interruption should always be as short as possible* and only used to *manage flags which alter the behaviour of your main code block*.

Hope this helped, comment any question that you might have with what I've explained.

Note: The code only wants to give you an idea of how to manage interruption, so it may not be the one that fits your needs.

Comment: Good answer, but both global flags should be `volatile`.

Comment: Can you explain what volatile variables are? I don't recall it as of now but know it is important, much time since I last touched an embedded

Comment: The `volatile` keyword means that the underlying value *might* change and so the compiler shouldn't, for example, cache the value when generating code.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018942/what-is-the-significance-of-the-volatile-key-word-with-respect-to-embedded-sys) for more.

Comment: Also you should fix the name of the variable within the `TimerInterrupt` code and make the value `true` instead of `1`.

Comment: I suggest default initializing the global flags to some deterministic explicit value.

Comment: They should be set to false but you are right, I'll correct it